# Simple way to get surrounding area name like Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, location, geonames

[image: Facebook App - Post New]

Hi all,

In Facebook app, when adding a new post, the app show **surrounding area name**.

This way of sharing place is cool, since it's automatically, and users don't need to choose from a list of venue names like Instagram app.

What is a quick way to get the same result as Facebook app?

Answer (score 1):

I've used similar things before through services like google maps api.

https://developers.google.com/maps/

You can pass them a lat and long and get various bits of info back.

I'm not sure if that is now a paid service though. It wasn't when I last used it but I think it changed.

There may be other similar services available.

A more specific page from Google maps api...

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: Thanks for very nice link. However "Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day."

Comment: Just had a read, the limit is 25,000 per day. Not 2,500 per day. If you think you'll be able to get that then you're either very lucky or very good :D You can pay for more if you go over that limit though.

Comment: 25,000 is "map load", not "geocoding". After more read, found that 2,500 is **per IP**, so should be good. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12500404/192800

Comment: Ah, that's cool :D couldn't see a separate geocoding usage limit so assumed the same.

Answer (score 1):

I found that iOS have a built-in api `CLGeocoder`, this is more convenient to use than Web API:

```
- (void)reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)location completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
```

This return you `CLPlacemark` with places, and areas.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: That's awesome. Not heard of that before. Will be using that in furute.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a detailed comparison of all the geolocation solutions - Foursquare, Facebook, Google etc etc - http://crschmidt.net/blog/archives/463/working-with-place-apis-aka-how-i-spent-my-spring-vacation/

But this is actually what you are looking for if you intend to use Facebook Graph APIs for "places" - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/show-nearby-places/

Specifically step 3 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/show-nearby-places/#step3)

> Now that you have the current location, use it with the
>   FBPlacePickerViewController object to show the place picker when the
>   user taps on the ''Where are you?'' menu option.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for a lot more choose Calvin. FBPlacePickerViewController is cool. I will check it in future, when I add function that allow user to choose location. Right now, I just want the UX as simple as posible, location is shown automatically, users don't need to choose from a list.